# AB=I matrix problem

Tags: matrices

if A and B are square matrix and satisfy this AB=i find A and B matrix
Can we say that A is sufficient condition for each element in b to be an integer is that detA is an integer or
Can we say that Because is always an integer matrix
Or is it possible to say that A necessary condition for each element in B to be an integer is determinant A lie in {-1,1}

Comment: Please add periods and capitalise properly it is hard to follow what you are saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take the matrix
$$
A=diag(2,\frac{1}{2}),
$$
and $B=A^{-1}$. Then $\det(A)=\det(B)=1$, but the matrix coefficients are not all integers.